# Handling Redirects within a Saved Website

Tags: android, caching, redirect, hyperlink, android-webview

I am working on a front-end Android app to a website. One of its features is to save portions of the site offline. The problem I am running into is when the user has saved two pages  of the site, where one links to the other.

Say for example, an *"About Me"* page that has a `<a href="projects>Projects<a>`.

The user also has that project page saved. What I want to happen is for the app to open up the offline *"Projects"* page when the link is clicked. This has to always work, even when there is no internet connection.

This leads me to the problem. The site links are almost all 302 redirects. So the links inside *"About Me"* open some other page where the redirect command is to get to the *"Projects"* page. I don't know how to get around this when there is no active internet connection. (Or why they have done it like this. Maybe organization? SEO?)

What makes it worse is when there are hundreds of nested links. This is not an unlikely occurrence. I don't have much experience in web programming so there could be some trick I don't know about.

Any help or guidance would be truly appreciated.

Thanks,
Julian